# Why adonis function DF changes with different factors combination?

Tags: r, vegan

```
> data(dune) 
> data(dune.env)  
> str(dune.env)  
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  5 variables:
$ A1        : num  2.8 3.5 4.3 4.2 6.3 4.3 2.8 4.2 3.7 3.3 ...
$ Moisture  : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1"<"2"<"4"<"5": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 4 3 2 ...
$ Management: Factor w/ 4 levels "BF","HF","NM",..: 4 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
$ Use       : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Hayfield"<"Haypastu"<..: 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 1 1 ...
$ Manure    : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 5 3 5 5 3 3 4 4 2 2 ...
```

As shown above, Moisture has four groups and Management has four groups, Manure has five groups when I run:

```
adonis(dune ~ Manure*Management*A1*Moisture, data=dune.env, permutations=99)

Call:
adonis(formula = dune ~ Manure * Management * A1 * Moisture,      data = dune.env, permutations = 99) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 99

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

              Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)
Manure             4    1.5239 0.38097 2.03088 0.35447   0.13
Management         2    0.6118 0.30592 1.63081 0.14232   0.16
A1                 1    0.3674 0.36743 1.95872 0.08547   0.21
Moisture           3    0.6929 0.23095 1.23116 0.16116   0.33
Manure:Management  1    0.1091 0.10906 0.58138 0.02537   0.75
Manure:A1          4    0.3964 0.09909 0.52826 0.09220   0.91
Management:A1      1    0.1828 0.18277 0.97431 0.04251   0.50
Manure:Moisture    1    0.0396 0.03963 0.21126 0.00922   0.93
Residuals          2    0.3752 0.18759         0.08727       
Total             19    4.2990                 1.00000
```

Why is DF of Management not 3(4-1)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general, rather than a specific answer.

Your formula `Moisture*Management*A1*Manure` corresponds to a linear model with 160 (!) predictors (`2*4*4*5`):

```r
dim(model.matrix(~Moisture*Management*A1*Manure, dune.env))
```

`adonis` builds this model matrix internally and uses it to construct the machinery for calculating the permutation statistics. When there are multicollinear combinations of predictors, it drops enough columns to make the problem well-defined again. The detailed rules for which columns get dropped depends on the order of the columns; if you reorder the factors in your question you'll see the reported `Df` change.

For what it's worth, I don't think the df calculations change the statistical outcomes at all — the statistics are based on the distributions derived from permutations, not from an analytical calculation that depends on the df.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Bolker got it right. If you only look at `Management` and `Manure` and forget all other variables, you will see this:

```
> with(dune.env, table(Management, Manure))
          Manure
Management 0 1 2 3 4
        BF 0 2 1 0 0
        HF 0 1 2 2 0
        NM 6 0 0 0 0
        SF 0 0 1 2 3
```

Look at row `Management NM` and column `Manure 0` that only have one non-zero case. This means that `Management NM` and `Manure 0` are synonyms, the same thing (or "aliased"). After you have had `Manure` in your model, `Management` only has three new levels, and hence 2 d.f. If you do it in reversed order and first have `Management` then you only have four levels `Manure` that you do not yet know, and that would give you 3 d.f. of `Manure`.

Although you really have overparametrized your model, you would also get the same result with only these two variables. Compare models:

```
adonis2(dune ~ Manure + Management, data=dune.env)
adonis2(dune ~ Management + Manure, data=dune.env)
```